# disable zend layout by javascript call

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, zend-framework

i am fetching a page using get ajax call.

```
$.get('/notification/viewmessage',{user:username},function(data){
                //my code here
            });
```

i wan't to disable the layout of the page on some `$.get` calls only.
the default layout disable function in zend is `$this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();`
but i don't want to do this in all page requests.
can i do this by adding some code in the js request itself?
thanks in advance.

Comment: you could add a variable to the URL then check that in the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd probably want to add a flag to your viewmessage script.

```
$.get('/notification/viewmessage?layout=false',{user:username},function(data){
    //my code here
});
```

Then in the viewmessage script you'd have something like this at the top of the script.

```
if($this->getRequest()->getParam('layout') == 'false')
{
    $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what the [AjaxContext action helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.contextswitch.ajaxcontext) does out of the box.

Simply add the config calls to your controller's `init()` method, create a `.ajax.phtml` view and render it in your normal view script. For example

```
public function init()
{
    $this->_helper->ajaxContext->addActionContext('viewmessage', 'html')
                               ->initContext('html');
                               // this avoids having to pass a format param
}
```

In `notification/viewmessage.phtml`

```
<?php echo $this->render('notification/viewmessage.ajax.phtml') ?>
```

and place your normal view contents in `notification/viewmessage.ajax.phtml`